# Oozie - Got exception running sqoop: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to perform an sqoop export on HDP sandbox 2.1 via Oozie. When I run the Oozie job I get the following java runtime exception.

> '>>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>
>
> 7598 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR
>   has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional
>   configuration.
>
> 7714 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version:
>   1.4.4.2.1.1.0-385
>
> 7760 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions  - Character argument
>   '\t' has multiple characters; only the first will be used.
>
> 7791 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has
>   not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional
>   configuration.
>
> 7904 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - Preparing
>   to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
>
> 7905 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool  - Beginning code
>   generation
>
> 7946 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Got exception running
>   Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Intercepting System.exit(1)

I have copied jdbc driver file "mysql-connector-java.jar" to Oozie's shared library folder which I believe is "/usr/lib/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/". I have restarted my sandbox and tried to perform the export with Oozie again and I still get the same error.

The export works perfectly fine when I try performing it only via sqoop, so I presume Oozie needs its own set of drivers.

My question is, which Oozie directory am I suppose to copy my jdbc drivers to?

If you guys think I'm doing something wrong or you need further information, please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "which I believe is" part of the CLASSPATH.  Apparently that assumption is wrong....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oozie + Sqoop: JDBC Driver Jar Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978156/oozie-sqoop-jdbc-driver-jar-location)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Duffymo, could you please elaborate your first comment regarding the class path? I did check question you mentioned in your second comment, I am still not able to run my job in spite of having the drivers in that folder.

Comment: Read the error messages.  I'd check to see if the SQOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable should be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally for Oozie the sharelib directory is /user/oozie/share/lib/ on HDFS where "oozie" would be the name of the user which is used to  start the Oozie Server. I don't know what that is in case of HDP sandbox 2.1 , but you can use ps command to figure that out.

And for jars needed for sqoop action, I think you should copy the jar to /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/ folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gaurav, it works. I added my drivers to /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop on HDP.