# Oozie Shared Lib: where to place jars

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, sqoop2, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have installed Cloudera CDH QuickStart VM 5.5, and I'm running a Sqoop action in my Oozie workflow. I encountered an error that says MySQL JDBC driver is missing and I came across to a SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978156/oozie-sqoop-jdbc-driver-jar-location) that says the mysql-connector-java.jar should be placed in Oozie's HDFS shared lib path, under `sqoop` path.

When I browse the Oozie's HDFS shared lib path, however, I've noticed two `sqoop` subdirectories to copy the jar.

```
/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop
```

and

```
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/sqoop
```

Aside from `sqoop`, `hive`, `pig`, `distcp`, and `mapreduce-streaming` paths also exist on both `lib` and `lib/lib_20151118030154`.

So the question is: where do I place my connector jar: on the first or the second one?

What's the difference (or difference of purpose) of these two paths in relation to jars of `sqoop`, `hive`, `pig`, `distcp`, and `mapreduce-streaming` for Oozie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lib_20151118030154` sub-dir would be the *current version* of the ShareLibs, as of 18-NOV-2015. The versioning allows you to make updates without stopping the Oozie service -- check the documentation [here](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Getting_list_of_available_sharelib).

In other words: the Oozie service keeps in memory a list of the JARs in each ShareLib (based on what was present for the latest version at boot time), so that adding a JAR will not make a difference until *(a)* you stop/restart the service or *(b)* you resync the service as explained in the doc above.